# How to set up a POC environment with DC/OS, Kafka and ElasticSearch on two nodes with Docker Swarm or Kubernetes containers?

Tags: elasticsearch, apache-kafka, kubernetes, docker-swarm, dcos

The instructions for [installing Mesosphere DC/OS on AWS](https://dcos.io/docs/1.7/administration/installing/cloud/aws/) use a CloudFormation template where the minimum configuration indicates:

> You have the option of 1 or 3 Mesos master nodes. 
>   5 private Mesos agent nodes is the default. 
>   1 public Mesos agent node is the default.

For our POC, as not to incur too much up-front cost, is it possible to do this all with two nodes?  One for DC/OS and the other containterized with ElasticSearch and Kafka?

If not, what would be a good configuration for this type of architecture?

Answer (score 2):

DC/OS does not run on Docker Swarm or Kubernetes. But you can run a development docker-in-docker local deployment on linux (or in a VM on mac/windows): [dcos-docker](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-docker)

You could then install ElasticSearch and Kafka on top of DC/OS.

You could also use [dcos-vagrant](https://github.com/dcos/dcos-vagrant) to run a multiple VM DC/OS local dev cluster.

Warning: the current vagrant v1.9.1 has a [crippling centos network bug](https://github.com/mitchellh/vagrant/issues/8096), if you need a VM. dcos-vagrant has a monkey patch workaround included, dcos-docker does not.

Comment: I'm trying to limit the number of servers for the POC.  So you can't point DCOS to specific containers on a server and install from the Universe?  i.e.  Through the DCOS CLI install Kafka on one container on server 2, and ElasticSearch on container 2 on server 2?

Comment: I don't know what you're asking, ElHaix. Containers are not generally limited to one per server.

Comment: My understanding was that you could have many containers on one server, all using the same server resources, no?    I know you can install Kubernetes through DC/OS, and just read that you can install Docker containers through DC/OS. I wanted to know about installing services (Kafka, etc.) on Docker containers through DC/OS.

Comment: K8s on DC/OS is no longer supported, but it does work on Mesos. IBM adopted that project from Mesosphere. The Mesosphere-supported DC/OS services are mostly documented on the [Mesosphere docs site](https://docs.mesosphere.com/), [kafka](https://docs.mesosphere.com/1.8/usage/service-guides/kafka/) for example.